# .prepend() .append() are deleting the original content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm am trying to copy all the content from div with id ajax-container within another div with class newContent.
i have tried this using: prepend, append and html that are deleting the original content and the clone function is not working.

```
$(".newContent").html($("#ajax-container")).html();

  $('.newContent').prepend($('#ajax-container'));
```

those are deleting the original div

The clone method is not copying all content of the page, only the first div.
I want to copy all the content in that div.
I found some questions here but it didn't help.

```
$('#ajax-container').clone().appendTo('.newContent');
```

this puts only the parrent div, not all inside it

```
var $comt=$("#ajax-container").children().clone(true,true);
   $(".newContent").html($comt).html();
```

this doesn't work at all

the `newContent` div is inside page.php in wordpress theme made with underscores in a root position and the `ajax-container` is in the header section. the content of the ajax-container div si loaded via ajax.

```
<section class="viewport" id="content">
        <div class="right">

            <div class="front" id="ajax-container" ></div>
            ...

        </div>


    </section>
```

this is the jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("ul.nav-menu> li a").on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();//stop loading the new link
 //  e.stopPropagation();
   var url = this.href;
   $('ul.nav-menu> li a.current').removeClass('current');
   $(this).addClass('current');
   $("#primary.content-area").remove();//remove old content
   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "html",
       success: function (res) {
           $("#ajax-container").html($(res).find("#primary.content-area")
               .addClass('done'))
               .fadeIn('slow');
       }
   });

   //var amount =360;
   //$("#ajax-container").clone().insertAfter("header#masthead.site-header");
   //var $comt=$("#ajax-container").children().clone(true,true);
   //$(".newContent").html($("#ajax-container")).html();

  //$('.newContent').prepend($('#ajax-container'));

   //$('#ajax-container').clone().appendTo('.newContent');
  // $(".newContent").html($("#ajax-container").html());
   var getContent = $('#ajax-container').html();
   $('.newContainer').append(getContent);
```

});

});

***I am using wordpress and the content that dissapears is added up by ajax. I have posted the jquery file above.***

```
$('div#ajax-container.front.PageLandingFront').clone().appendTo($('div#primary.content-area'));
```

this line makes the copy but the target div doesn't have all html inside it, only the root div element. Any ideas?

I finally sort it out and this is what i was doing wrong:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (res) {
            $("#ajax-container").html($(res).find("#primary.content-area").addClass('done')).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        complete: function () {
                $('div#ajax-container.front.PageLandingFront').children().clone().appendTo($('div#primary.content-area'));
                $('div#ajax-container.front.PageLandingFront').html("");
        }
    })
```

It seems that i had that error because of ajax function that was loading at the same time with my clone so i had to make sure that the ajax call is done when i want to clone that div. Thanks for your support!
This topic can be closed because my problem was solved!

Comment: `$comt` and `comt` are different variables.

Comment: still not working...

Comment: try `$(".newContent").html($("#ajax-container").html());`

Comment: this is not doing anything.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not quite working is because you are using a class selector. Give the containing div an id and then try it.

```
$("#newContent").append($("#ajax-container").html());
```

Comment: i have tried this way but still no result $("div.newContent").append($("div#ajax-container.front")).html();

Answer (score 0):

As per spec of the jQuery API, the `clone` method creates a deep clone of the given element, including the element itself. If you require the element itself, pick one of these three:

```
$('.newContent').append($('#ajax-container').clone());

$('#ajax-container').clone().appendTo('.newContent');

$('#ajax-container').clone().appendTo($('.newContent'));
```

If you want only the children inside the given element, you could use this one of these.

```
$('.newContent').append($('#ajax-container').children().clone());

$('#ajax-container').children().clone().appendTo('.newContent');

$('#ajax-container').children().clone().appendTo($('.newContent'));
```

Comment: first 3 are also deleting the div that has id ajax-container and the others are not working at all

Comment: Then you must be missing something else, since I actually get clones. Could you provide your complete code? Including jQuery version.

Comment: the code is made over underscores, i don't know how can i provide the entire code. i am using this version. https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: That is a really outdated version of jQuery. Why aren't you using ver 2.2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

And, this works just fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var getContent = $('#ajax-container').html();
    $('.newContainer').append(getContent);
})
```

```css
div {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<body>
   <div id="ajax-container">
    <p>something goes here</p>
    <p>and something goes here</p>
   </div>
   <div class="newContainer">
    <p>this is the new container</p>
   </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If this is working then it must be somewhere else the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note in the Snippet the content `.first` is not overwritten nor has the nested content (`.nested` in pink) been abandoned. Also note when you use `.html()` or `.text()`, it will overwrite the destination's content. Click the <kbd>COPY</kbd> button to run. Details are commented within the Snippet.

#### SNIPPET

```js
/* Delegate click event to #btn1...
|  ...collect the children elements of #ajaxContainer
|  deep clone them then append them to .newContent
*/
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  $('#ajaxContainer').children().clone(true, true).appendTo('.newContent');
});
```

```css
#ajaxContainer,
.newContent {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 125px;
}
#ajaxContainer {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.newContent {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.nested {
  color: pink;
  border: 1px dotted pink;
}
.content {
  border: 2px solid lime;
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
  color: lime;
}
.first {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
#btn1 {
  float: right;
  border: 3px dashed orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='btn1'>COPY</button>
<section id='ajaxContainer'>
  <span class='content'>CONTENT</span>
  <div class='content'>CONTENT</div>
  <div class='content'>CONTENT
    <small class='nested'>NESTED</small>
  </div>
</section>

<section class='newContent'>
  <div class='first'>FIRST</div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for support, but for me it is not working. I think the problem is from somewhere else inside my code. I will sort it out some way. Thank you very much!

Comment: yes, i am using wordpress and that div that i want to clone has content with ajax and after some research i think this is the problem but i don't know what should i do.

Comment: Are there any iframes on the page?

Comment: No. Content from .ajax() function is loaded in a div that has id ajax-container.

Comment: You might consider [shortcode](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72974/use-ajax-in-shortcode)